# AllowOverride not working for alias'd site

Tags: apache2, alias

I have a two domains `johny.com` and `alice.com` and one webserver (apache) managing them. Web files are in `/var/www/johny.com` and `/var/www/alice.com` and are configured as two virtual hosts with proper `ServerName` and `DocumentRoot`. Now Alice wants to protect one of her files on the web from anyone seeing. She introduces a `.htaccess` file with the following content

```
<Files "private.txt">
  Require all denied
</Files>
```

and also adds following to the apache config for her virtual host

```
<Directory /var/www/alice.com>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

And nobody has access to `alice.com/private.txt`. So far so good.

Now John decides to provide an alias for Alice's web by altering his vhost apache configuration with

```
Alias "/alice" "/var/www/alice.com"
```

and anyone can see Alice's web page on `john.com/alice`. But anyone can also see the content of alice's private file.

`alice.com/private.txt` gives 403 Forbidden.
`john.com/alice/private.txt` shows the content of the file.

What is going on in here? Does `AllowOverride` not propagate through `Alias` directive? How should we fix that? Apache version is `Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)`. Also putting gibberish into `.htaccess` file gives 500 Internal Server Error only on `alice.com`, not on `john.com/alice`, so it seems like the `.htaccess` is not considered over an alias at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a missing `AllowOverride All` directive for the `/var/www/alice.com` directory.

Specifically, the problem is here: (emphasis mine)

> and also adds following to the apache config ***for her virtual host***

Since you defined those directory permissions inside Alice's virtual host block, they don't apply to `john.com/alice` because the directory is not being accessed through the context of the `<VirtualHost>` block corresponding to Alice. As far as the server is concerned, the alias is legally accessing some directory in the filesystem. It just so happens that it's the same directory as the root of a different virtual host.

[From the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging):

> Sections inside  sections are applied after the corresponding sections outside the virtual host definition. This allows virtual hosts to override the main server configuration.

As it pertains to your particular case, however, it's important to note that this will only actually happen if the `VirtualHost` context corresponding to the sections in question is actually invoked, which it isn't here.

There are a couple of ways to fix this problem. The easiest is to simply declare the `AllowOverride All` directive in the [server context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) (i.e... not within a `VirtualHost`, `.htaccess`, or even another `Directory` block.

```
<Directory "/var/www/alice.com">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Note again that because you are declaring `AllowOverride All`, you'll be able to modify these settings within the `.htaccess` file in that directory now, regardless of the `VirtualHost` context the directory is being accessed from.

If you wanted to get fancy, and you were dead-set on accessing `/var/www/alice.com` from `john.com` but within `alice.com`'s virtual host context, you could always configure the `john.com/alice` uri to be `ProxyPass`'d to `http://alice.com`.

```
<VirtualHost "*:80">
    ...

    <Location "/alice">
        ProxyPreserveHost Off
        ProxyPass http://alice.com/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

You'll need to enable `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` for the above, but it'll meet your requirements for this particular use case, although I would be careful about relying on the `Location` directive for reasons which [the documentation does a great job of delineating at length](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location).